# OneSignal: How to Handle notificationOpened in AppDelegate of a Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, onesignal

I am working on implementing OneSignal push-notification in Xamarin.Forms.

I need to pass the string returned by OneSignal `AdditionalData` into the constructor of `App()`.

So I used `HandleNotificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenedResult result)` for handling the notification tap and fetching the string and then pass it to `LoadApplication(new App(myData))`.

So for this, I have written the code in `MainActivity` for Android and in `AppDelegate` for iOS.

Everything is working fine for Android; i.e. the `HandleNotificationOpened()` fetched the `additionalData` and passes it to`LoadApplication(new App(myData))`.

But in iOS, when I opened the notification, the `HandleNotificationOpened()` code is not called.

## AppDelegate.cs

```
static string s = null;

public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    OneSignal.Current.StartInit("MyKey").HandleNotificationOpened(HandleNotificationOpened).EndInit();
    
    if(s!=null)
    {
        LoadApplication(new App(s));
    }
    else
    {
        LoadApplication(new App("myUrl.lasso")); 
    }

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}

private static void HandleNotificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenedResult result)
{
    OSNotificationPayload payload = result.notification.payload;
    Dictionary<string, object> additionalData = payload.additionalData;

    if (additionalData != null)
    {
        if (additionalData.ContainsKey("url_direct"))
        {
            s = additionalData["url_direct"].ToString();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We need to redirect it to: " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a work-around. 
Actually we can not catch notification tap on AppDelegate's finishedLaunching() thats why HandleNotificationOpened(HandleNotificationOpened) is not working properly in iOS. So I have implemented it on PCL common folder App class.

Answer (score 8):

## Answer

Override the `DidReceivedRemoteNotification` `event` in `AppDelegate`.

## Code

```
public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, System.Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
{
    base.DidReceiveRemoteNotification(application, userInfo, completionHandler);

    NSDictionary aps = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;
            
    string alert = string.Empty;
    if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("alert")))
        alert = (aps [new NSString("alert")] as NSString).ToString();

    if (application.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Active)
    {
        //app is currently active, you can get your payload (userInfo) data here
    }
    else if (application.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Background)
    {
        //app is in background, you can get your payload (userInfo)
    }
    else if (application.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive)
    {
        //app is transitioning from background to foreground (user taps notification), do what you need when user taps here, you can get your payload (userInfo)
    }
}
```